# Dealing with the environment url in the "build" version of react

Tags: reactjs, django

I'm trying to deploy a react-django app to production using digitalocean droplet. I have a file where I check for the current environment (development or production), and based on the current environment assign the appropriate url to use to connect to the django backend like so:

```
export const server = enviroment ? "http://localhost:8000" : "domain-name.com";
```

My app is working perfectly both on development and production modes in local system (I temporarily still used http://localhost:8000 in place of domain-name.com). But I observed something rather strange. It's the fact that when I tried to access the site (still in my local computer) with "127.0.0.1:8000" ON THE BROWSER, the page is blank with a console error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' ....".
When I changed it back to "http://localhost:8000", everything was back working. My worry is isn't 127.0.0.1:8000 the same as http://localhost:8000? From this I conclude that whatever you have in the domain-name.com place when you build your react frontend is exactly what will be used.

Like I said, I'm trying to deploy to a digital ocean droplet, and I plan to install ssl certificate so the site could be served on https. Now my question is given the scenario painted above, what should be the right way to write the url in production? Should it be "serverIP-address", "domain-name.com", "http://domain-name.com", "https://domain-name.com" ?.

I must mentioned that I had previously attempted to deploy to the said platform using the IP-address in the domain-name.com place. After following all the steps. I got a 502 (Bad gateway) error. However, I'm not saying using Ip address was responsible for the error in that case.

Please I would appreciate any help especially from someone who had previously deployed a react-django app to the said platform. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> From this I conclude that whatever you have in the domain-name.com
> place when you build your react frontend is exactly what will be used.

Not exactly true, the domain from which the react app is served will be used. If you build it local and upload it to the server and configure domain.com to serve it, then domain.com will be used for cors. The best idea is to allow all CORS until your project is deployment ready. Once done, whitelist the domain.com

Answer (score 0):

The solution actually lies in providing the host(s) allowed to connect to the Back-end in the **`setting.py`** file like so: `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [ domain-name.com, https:domain-name.com , ... ]` etc. That way, you wouldn't be tied to using the url provided in the react environment variable. Though I have not deployed to the server, my first worry within the local machine is taken care off.